# Need to change GUID to varchar or char

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, guid

I am trying to use a reference table to update a code, but I am getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to
>   uniqueidentifier

The ID is a guid: **086B9FE7-3980-47D7-BB05-003708F1D564** and the reference code I want to use is 4 characters, like **H100**.

I received the initial error when I tried to alter the datatype in the table and then update the file with the values from the reference table. I have tried converting and casting based on other articles, but even if I cast or convert successfully, I still get the same message.

**RefTable:**

```
Id                                   |  ReportCode
6340FCEA-161C-42F4-8D7F-46B4C2E6C4E2 |  H100
```

**DataTable:**

```
CauseId
6340FCEA-161C-42F4-8D7F-46B4C2E6C4E2
```

Code I am using to try and update. The first works, and the second bring the error msg:

```
select cast(nvarchar(36), ID) as ID
from [dbo].[reftable]

UPDATE dbo.datatable
SET    causeid = L.reportcode
FROM   dbo.datatable S 
join dbo.reftable L on S.causeid = L.id
```

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Update a GUID field with a different GUID? Change the column type itself? It's not clear. But if the column type is uniqueidentifier then it needs to be an actual 36 character uniqueidentifier format and `H100` won't ever work. If you provide some code or sample it would be much easier to assist.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it

Comment: Ok, so is there a ReportCode field in DataTable as well as RefTable?

Comment: You need to change your table column to `VARCHAR`. Please post the error it throws when you try to `ALTER TABLE dbo.datatable ALTER COLUMN causeid VARCHAR(200)`. `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` requiers a very particular string format, with hyphens and exactly 36 bytes, which the value 'H100' doesn't comply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Uniqueidentifier` is a particular column type that holds 36 bytes, with some hyphen characters in the middle. Asigning a string value that doesn't match it's format will always fail when trying to convert it.

```
-- Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 'H100')

-- OK
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 'c029f8be-29dc-41c1-8b38-737b4cc5a4df')
```

If you want to use a common `VARCHAR` as your new `causeid` value, you need to first convert the column type to `VARCHAR` (or `NVARCHAR`).

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.datatable ALTER COLUMN causeid VARCHAR(200) -- NOT NULL if you need
```

If you can't alter the data type it's probably because there is an `INDEX` or a `CONSTRAINT` linked to it. When you try to alter, the SQL engine will tell you which object is linked to it. You will have to drop them, alter the column type and then create them again.

I use these queries to check indexes and constraints. I updated the search values for your table.

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(200) = 'datatable'
DECLARE @column_name VARCHAR(200) = 'causeid'

 -- Indexes
SELECT
     SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id),
     TableName = t.name,
     IndexName = ind.name,
     IndexType = CASE ind.index_id WHEN 0 THEN 'Heap' WHEN 1 THEN 'Clustered' ELSE 'Nonclustered' END,
     Disabled = ind.is_disabled,
     ColumnOrder = ic.index_column_id,
     ColumnName = col.name,
     ColumnType = y.name,
     ColumnLength = y.max_length,
     ColumnIncluded = ic.is_included_column
FROM 
    sys.indexes ind 
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.types y ON y.user_type_id = col.user_type_id
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
    t.name = @table_name AND
    col.name = @column_name
ORDER BY
    SchemaName,
    t.name, 
    ind.name, 
    ic.index_column_id

-- Constraints
SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    dc.Name,
    dc.definition
FROM 
    sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
WHERE
    t.name = @table_name AND
    c.name = @column_name
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```